# String date to unix timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, timestamp

I m working on a scheduled TV on a raspberry pi (raspbian) in javascript/node.js

I extract the information of what to play in a .smil file, and one of the field is scheduled, wich is a string of the format "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss"

To make comparison between them and the system time, I would like to convert it in UNIX timestamp.

Is there a better way than a function like this one:

```
function (stime){
    var time=0, cache=0, scache;

    scache=stime.substr(0, 4);
    cache=parseInt(scache);
    time=cache*365*24*60*60;

    ...

    return time;
}
```

And so on for mounth, day...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be this can help

```
var date = new Date('2009-07-15 00:00:00'.split(' ').join('T'))
```

that will give you date object and to get timestamp from it you can do

```
date.getTime() / 1000
```

dividing by 1000 because getTime will give timestamps in milliseconds

Comment: I don't think it returns it as milliseconds anymore

Comment: For such date: ```"2016-05-10T19:27:21.338Z"``` method ```.getTime()/1000``` delivers ```1462908441.338```.

I propose the following snippet for such case:

   ```~~(date.getTime() / 1000)```